# What happens when you scan your 31st Amiibo in Amiibo Tap?

Tags: wii-u, amiibo, amiibo-tap-nintendos-greatest-bits

Each time you scan an Amiibo in Amiibo Tap: Nintendo's Greatest Bits, it unlocks a virtual console demo that is tied to the Amiibo you scanned to unlock it.

There are 30 game demos. What happens if, after unlocking all 30 with different Amiibo, you scan a 31st Amiibo?

Comment: Doesn't it unlock a demo that's related to the Amiibo you scan? I suppose Amiibo Tap will just tell you your Amiibo isn't supported. I'm guessing the Splatoon Amiibos would be like that.

Comment: No, I've tested it, it unlocks a *random* demo for each Amiibo, that way it will work with any that are ever released..   My Mario unlocked Link to the Past and my Link Unlocked Donkey Kong.

Comment: I would figure it wouldn't do anything...  But there could be a secret... Now you got me all curious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 30 Amiibos you scan unlocks a random locked game, tied to the Amiibo, but not necessary related to its character (Mario may unlock The Legend of Zelda, for example).

Each Amiibo scanned after the 30th will unlock a random (already) unlocked game, which will also be tied to the Amiibo.

This will not break the liaison between the Amiibo that previously unlocked and the twice unlocked game, meaning that tapping any two Amiibos will let you play the game, and switch between scenes like if both Amiibos were the same one.